# Host and target machine

Tags: cross-compilation

Can someone explain what host machine represent, and what target machine represent, when configuring cross-compilers?

Comment: Looking at `configure --help` is just enough.

Answer (score 5):

- **Host**: The environment you are running the compiler on.
- **Target**: The environment you are compiling something for.